# Python csv: group datetime column having millisecond value with interval of 15 minutes and add a new csv column with time-bucket name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv, datetime

I have csv column with below datetime value having milliseconds values.

```
20-07-10 16:00:08.155
20-07-10 16:10:30.745
20-07-10 16:34:09.246
20-07-10 16:46:00.961
20-07-10 16:56:04.129
20-07-10 17:06:09.536
20-07-10 18:06:26.568
20-07-10 18:26:36.569
20-07-10 18:36:50.560
20-07-10 18:47:06.114
20-07-10 18:57:25.397
```

I need to group the times by every 15 minutes of the hour and add a new column having the start time of 15 minutes interval. The output should have an extra column in the csv with the time bucket shown as below.

```
20-07-10 16:00:08.155       20-07-10 16:00
20-07-10 16:10:30.745       20-07-10 16:00
20-07-10 16:34:09.246       20-07-10 16:30
20-07-10 16:46:00.961       20-07-10 16:45
20-07-10 16:56:04.129       20-07-10 16:45
20-07-10 17:06:09.536       20-07-10 17:00
20-07-10 18:06:26.568       20-07-10 18:00
20-07-10 18:26:36.569       20-07-10 18:15
20-07-10 18:36:50.560       20-07-10 18:30
20-07-10 18:47:06.114       20-07-10 18:45
20-07-10 18:57:25.397       20-07-10 18:45
```

my present code looks like below

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

in_path = "input.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(in_path)
time_utc = df['DATE_TIME_2'] # in csv file, "DATE_TIME_2" column has the datetime value.
print(time_utc)
time_utc['time_bucket'] = time_utc.apply(lambda x: "perdio_%d"%(int(x['DATE_TIME_2'].minute/15)))
print(time_utc)
```

But above code gives me below error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

If instead of lambda I use any of below,

```
time_utc.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15Min')).first()
time_utc.resample('15min').first()
```

I get the below error:

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or
> PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

Comment: Note: I've checked the existing answers but the solutions not solving my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html)    :

```
time_utc['time_bucket'] = time_utc['DATE_TIME_2'].dt.floor('15Min')
print (time_utc)
               DATE_TIME_2         time_bucket
0  2010-07-20 16:00:08.155 2010-07-20 16:00:00
1  2010-07-20 16:10:30.745 2010-07-20 16:00:00
2  2010-07-20 16:34:09.246 2010-07-20 16:30:00
3  2010-07-20 16:46:00.961 2010-07-20 16:45:00
4  2010-07-20 16:56:04.129 2010-07-20 16:45:00
5  2010-07-20 17:06:09.536 2010-07-20 17:00:00
6  2010-07-20 18:06:26.568 2010-07-20 18:00:00
7  2010-07-20 18:26:36.569 2010-07-20 18:15:00
8  2010-07-20 18:36:50.560 2010-07-20 18:30:00
9  2010-07-20 18:47:06.114 2010-07-20 18:45:00
10 2010-07-20 18:57:25.397 2010-07-20 18:45:00
```

Comment: Hellow, this worked perfectly!
Only thing is that the values read from CSV were not datetime values, hence I was getting [raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values")] error.
To solve this added the line [df['DATETIME_UTC'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATETIME_UTC'], errors='coerce')] before the line [time_utc = df['DATETIME_UTC']]